# Npoco Debugging and Profiling with version 3

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, .net-4.6.1, npoco

trying to implement this sample code to show last sql statement in the exception.

```
   public class MyDb : Database 
{
    public MyDb(string connectionStringName) : base(connectionStringName) { }

    public override void OnException(Exception e)
    {
        base.OnException(e);
        e.Data["LastSQL"] = this.LastSQL;
    }
}
```

but i am getting error on OnException.

> cannot change access modifier when overriding protected inherited memeber 'Database.OnException'

Any idea.

Answer (score 0):

The function override is protected and not public per the error message

```
public override void OnException(Exception e)
```

should be

```
protected override void OnException(Exception e)
```